# Multi condition Count Expression in Visual Studio

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, reporting-services, visual-studio-2017, expression

I am trying to add some report logic to save setting up another dataset. First thing I need is to count the number of rows per date, then number of rows per date where another column states = "Yes".

I have a raw data stored procedure which returns the data as a table, on another tab.

Comment: It sounds like _conditional aggregation_ might be applicable. Do you have a question? And DDL, sample data and expected results? And what you've tried and how it failed to meet your needs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Number of records that match date parameter:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields.DATE_FIELD.Value = Parameters!DATE_PARAM.Value, 1, 0))
```

Number of records that match date parameter where another column = YES:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields.DATE_FIELD.Value = Parameters!DATE_PARAM.Value AND Fields.OTHER_FIELD.Value = "Yes", 1, 0))
```

The IIF checks the conditions and if they are TRUE then return 1 for a record else 0 then it sums these values up.

UPDATE:
I think I misunderstood what you were needing.

You want to have a count of all records by date not just for a particular date.

For that you would want a table that groups by date, then you could just use a COUNTROWS or SUM(1) for the number of records for each date.

Then you could use an IIF to check for the Yes in the other field:

```
=SUM(IIF(Fields.OTHER_FIELD.Value = "Yes", 1, 0))
```

Since your table is already grouping by date, you don't need the date in the above expression.

Comment: Thanks for the help sorted what i was trying to do